# How to return multiple values in controller MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm trying to merge these 2 methods into 1 controller. So that I can return the products and students in one action.

The `Index()` captures an excel file name + file path and the Index2() inserts the excel file data into the database. My goal is to simply execute both with a simple click of submit button and I need to return these 2 multiple values on 1 controller.  Am I doing something wrong? Any tips would be welcome. Thanks

```cs
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Student products = GetProducts();
    ViewBag.Message = "";
    return View(products);
}     

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Student obj)
{
    string strDateTime = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHMMss");
    string finalPath = "\\excelfolder\\" + strDateTime + obj.UploadFile.FileName;

    obj.UploadFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~") + finalPath);
    obj.FilePath = strDateTime + obj.UploadFile.FileName;
    ViewBag.Message = SaveToDB(obj);
    Student products = GetProducts();
    ....
}

public ActionResult Index2()
{
    var studentList = _studentDAL.GetallStudents();

    if (studentList.Count == 0)
    {
        TempData["InfoMessage"] = "Student data unavailable in the Database.";
    }
    return View(studentList);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index2(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string filename = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

    string filepath = "/excelfolder/" + filename;

    file.SaveAs(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/excelfolder"), filename));

    InsertExceldata(filepath, filename);

    var studentList = _studentDAL.GetallStudents();

    return View(studentList);
}
```

Comment: In your question above you have **four** methods, but not **2**. Be more precisely, please, what methods you want to merge?

Comment: I want to return the products and studentList from a single controller to be able to execute it on a single submit button sir.